# Can MySQL be configured to visually display NULL values differently?

Tags: mysql

In the MySQL shell, when I enter "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE" and the result contains null values, what gets printed is NULL wherever there are null values. Is there a way to configure the MySQL shell to display nothing or an alternate label instead of NULL on the screen? I am not talking about editing the querying itself to return a different value when null, I am talking about a setting for how the shell renders null values on screen.

Comment: Could you please explain what will be the purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "NULL" string output appears to be hard-coded in the `get_as_row()` function in MySQL Shell.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-shell/blob/master/mysqlshdk/libs/db/row_copy.cc#L141-L148

```
std::string Mem_row::get_as_string(uint32_t index) const {
  VALIDATE_INDEX(index);

  if (is_null(index)) return "NULL";

  switch (get_type(index)) {
    case Type::Null:
      return "NULL";
```